# LibreOffice Writer Header

Tags: libreoffice

Every time I hover my cursor over the top/bottom of a page it displays a small box to add a header/footer

I am quite irritated by this behavior. How do I turn this feature off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot turn it off in the current (3.5) LibreOffice version. However, this has been bothering other people. The discussion [here](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=48444) points to [this page](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core/commit/?id=3d7927152169474c3c73ac36d5d79008fe6bab3e) containing a patch that makes the header/footer appear on a click, rather than mouseover. Starting with version 3.7, there should be a setting for this.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I implement the patch? I have no experience with this :)